# Rescale intensities of a PIL Image

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

What is the simplest/cleanest way to rescale the intensities of a PIL Image?

Suppose that I have a 16-bit image from a 12-bit camera, so only the values 0–4095 are in use.  I would like to rescale the intensities so that the entire range 0–65535 is used.  What is the simplest/cleanest way to do this when the image is represented as PIL's Image type?

The best solution I have come up with so far is:

```
pixels = img.getdata()
img.putdata(pixels, 16)
```

That works, but always leaves the four least significant bits blank.  Ideally, I would like to shift each value four bits to the left, then copy the four most significant bits to the four least significant bits.  I don't know how to do that fast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you know that the pixel values are 0-4095, I can't find a faster way than this:

```
new_image= image.point(lambda value: value<<4 | value>>8)
```

According to the [documentation](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm), the lambda function will be called at most 4096 times, whatever the size of your image.

EDIT: Since the function given to point *must* be of the form `argument * scale + offset` for in `I` image, then this is the best possible using the `point` function:

```
new_image= image.point(lambda argument: argument*16)
```

The maximum output pixel value will be 65520.

#### A second take:

A modified version of your own solution, using `itertools` for improved efficiency:

```
import itertools as it # for brevity
import operator

def scale_12to16(image):
    new_image= image.copy()
    new_image.putdata(
        it.imap(operator.or_,
            it.imap(operator.lshift, image.getdata(), it.repeat(4)),
            it.imap(operator.rshift, image.getdata(), it.repeat(8))
        )
    )
    return new_image
```

This avoids the limitation of the `point` function argument.

Comment: That is a very good idea, but because 16-bit images are if PIL type "I", the argument to `point` must be a function of the form `argument * scale + offset`.

Comment: You are correct, of course. Hopefully the "second take" should be efficient enough for you.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you want to copy the 4 msb back into the 4 lsb?  You only have 12 significant bits of information per pixel.  Nothing you do will improve that.  If you are OK with only having 4K of intensities, which is fine for most applications, then your solution is correct and probably optimal.  If you need more levels of shading, then as David posted, recompute using a histogram.  But, this will be significantly slower.

But, copying the 4 msb into the 4 lsb is NOT the way to go :)

Comment: The reason I thought to copy the 4 MSB is that it would use the entire range 0–(2^16-1), so saturated pixels in the original image will appear saturated in the rescaled image as well.

Comment: Indeed, this is the standard way of upscaling to a higher number of bits per channel.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do a histogram *stretch* ([link to a similar question I answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295057/i-need-to-do-a-histogram-stretch/1299079#1299079)) not histogram *equalization*:
[histogram stretch http://cct.rncan.gc.ca/resource/tutor/fundam/images/linstre.gif](http://cct.rncan.gc.ca/resource/tutor/fundam/images/linstre.gif)

[Image source](http://cct.rncan.gc.ca/resource/tutor/fundam/chapter4/05_e.php)

In your case you one need to **multiply** all the pixel values by **16**, which is the factor between the two dynamic ranges (65536/4096).

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is [Histogram Equalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_equalization).
For how to do it with python and pil:

- [LINK1](http://effbot.org/zone/pil-histogram-equalization.htm)
- [LINK2](http://jesolem.blogspot.com/2009/06/histogram-equalization-with-python-and.html)

EDIT:
Code to shift each value four bits to the left, then copy the four most significant bits to the four least significant bits...

```
def f(n):
   return  n<<4 + int(bin(n)[2:6],2)

print(f(0))
print(f(2**12))

# output
>>> 0
    65664 # Oops > 2^16
```

Comment: Both links are exactly the same

Comment: No, histogram equalization stretches different parts of the histogram differently.  What I want to do is simply to stretch the histogram evenly so as to use the entire intensity range.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should pass 16. (a float) instead of 16 (an int). I was trying to test it, but for some reason putdata does not multiply at all... So I hope it just works for you.